# Weibull statistics

Tags: plotting, fitting, logarithmic-scale

[image]I have two data sets am interested in finding the weibull modulus and characteristics strength for the two data sets and plotting the data seperately but on the same graph

Material (a)

723, 684, 541, 742, 584, 636, 671, 536, 693, 635 MPa

Material (b) 
for my x-axis I have the log of the data sets (every single value)
for the y axis the formula would be the log [log [1/[1-[n+1]/total]]
for example material a it would be log[log[1/[1-[1/10]]
this is my first time using mathematica, anything helps

Comment: Where are the two data sets and your code?

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* provides internal support for Weibull plots through the ProbabilityScalePlot[] function.  Here is an example where I generated material 2 by dividing material 1 by 2 since material 2 data were not provided.

```
m1 = {723, 684, 541, 742, 584, 636, 671, 536, 693, 635};
m2 = m1/2;
ProbabilityScalePlot[{m1, m2}, "Weibull", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, 
 PlotRange -> {{100, 900}, {1, 99}}]
```

[image: Weibull Plot]